# How to import title, description and image from website

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I would like to have a "Facebook style link commment" feature in Drupal 7. When you enter a URL it will pull the page title, first 100 characters of the main website text and an image.
There is a module called "[Facebook Style Micropublisher](http://drupal.org/project/fbsmp)" but it's Drupal 6 only.
Any other ideas on how this could get accomplished?

Comment: Will you be entering the url in a new node?

Comment: I would enter the URL and the parsed info into fields.  Over the weekend I stumbled across oembed.com (an open format to embed content) and http://embed.ly (a commercial site). There is even a module that seems to support both: http://drupal.org/project/oembed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual way to do it is to create a custom module that uses [drupal_http_request](http://api.lullabot.com/drupal_http_request/7) to download the remote URL, then parse through the resulting data to pull out any images, a summary, and the contents of the title tag.

This is a lot harder than it sounds because manually parsing HTML is actually pretty tricky. If you must take this approach, try using [simplexml](http://drewish.com/content/2007/08/using_simplexml_with_html) or a library that [tries to simplify things for you.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

A better approach might be just porting the Drupal 6 module yourself - it's probably less work and you could contribute your code back and possibly get patches from other contributors.